# Firefox doesn't execute function on scroll event

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I'm trying to make a div sticky only after the body's scrollTop is greater than its offsetTop. My solution works perfect on Chrome, yet Firefox doesn't seems to respond nor throw any errors.

My code:

```
var sticky = document.createElement('div');
sticky.style.width = "300px";
sticky.style.height = "600px";
sticky.style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.querySelector('*[id^="channel."]').parentElement.appendChild(sticky);
var sticky_offset = sticky.offsetTop;

function makeItStick() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > sticky_offset)  {
        sticky.style.position = "fixed";
        sticky.style.top = "0px";
    } else {
        sticky.style.position = "";
    }
};


window.addEventListener("scroll", makeItStick);
```

Comment: try using `DOMMousescroll`

Comment: Can you share the working code?

Comment: Any console messages? can you make a snippet (click the `<>` in the editor here)

Comment: Have you tried debugging the values of the `sticky.offsetTop` and `document.body.scrollTop` using `console.log()` or place a `debugger` statement near that code to check the values?

Comment: When you do scroll the page, it is the `scrollTop` value of `document.documentElement` which is updated, not the one of body, except if your CSS explecitely says body should have overflow and a max-height. But anyway, for better compatibility, use `window.pageYOffset` instead.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks! I've used 'window.pageYOffset' instead of 'document.body.scrollTop' and now it works in Firefox as well.